# Adding Image into Modal ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, modal-dialog, react-modal

I'm trying to insert and style an image in my modal but I'm having trouble doing it. I've tried wrapping the image under a div and apply properties to that div but it doesn't seem to be working either. I've created a link to my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-rx1dz?file=/src/App.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using simple string, you need to ref the image using `require`

```
<img src={require('./modal.jpg')} />
```

You can also use `import`

```
import img from "./modal.jpg"; 
<img src={img} />
```

I also changed a little bit the style in order to fit inside the div

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-forked-mpkzm

Comment: Oh the image appears fine on my side, but I was wondering how to style it properly. Because whatever css I apply, there doesnt seem to be any effect

Comment: ok because in the sandbox image was not appearing at all. so you nit to fit inside dialog. to fit width and height?

Comment: yup, i'm trying to split the modal into left and right. where left side will display the image, but all the css properties i've applied doesnt seem to work. It only works when i manually inspect element and apply it

Comment: Instead of applying the style directly in the App.js , is it possible to do it on the scss page?

Comment: a ok let me check. now i get what you want to achieve

Comment: Yeah because the image is wrapped under the Modal, and I can't seem to find the Modal default className

Comment: check the link again

Comment: Ah ok, I know how to go about it already. Thank you! By any chance, do you know how to style an 'x' icon as the close button?

Comment: check the icons here. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp. if my answer solved your problem, dont forget to accept it. thank you!